# Como recuperar o conteúdo de um template renderizado no Symfony2 e armazenar em uma String

Tags: php, symfony-2, twig, pjax

Estou usando o [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html), ainda estou me familiarizando com esse framework. E ao utilizar o meu controle não estou sabendo como pegar a saída gerada por ele e jogar para uma string. 
Eu preciso jogar para uma string para tratar, pois estou usando o [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) e se a requisição for uma requisição originada pelo [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) eu preciso mandar apenas um trecho da página (o conteúdo que eu quero modificar), para fazer isso eu pretendo usar o [Crawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) e dessa forma retornar apenas o conteúdo correto, dependendo da situação. O problema é que eu não sei como fazer como capturar o HTML que o Controller gera.

```
<?php
/**
 * State controller.
 *
 * @Route("/state")
 */
class StateController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Lists all State entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="state")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('AmbulatoryBundle:State')->findAll();

        $rendered = $this->render('TestBundle:State:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));

        return $rendered; // Preciso pegar o conteúdo gerado aqui em string
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O SF2 retorna o objeto `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` em seu `controller`.

Para você ter acesso à `string` Html, pode fazer deste modo:

```
<?php
/**
 * State controller.
 *
 * @Route("/state")
 */
class StateController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Lists all State entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="state")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('AmbulatoryBundle:State')->findAll();

        $response = $this->render('TestBundle:State:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));

        $html = $response->getContent(); // Faça algo com a string....

        return $response;
    }
```

Mais detalhes no [Doc do objeto](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html)